# PlatformException(exception, BAD_REQUEST, null, null)

Tags: flutter, google-signin

I use google_sign_in + Firebase to authenticate users.

This exception is thrown after I select my Google account and confirm the agreements.

```
PlatformException(exception, BAD_REQUEST, null, null)
```

Comment: My  emulator doesn't support Google Play

Comment: Install emulator SDK with Google API

Answer (score 5):

same issue and I solved it by adding scopes like so:

```
final googleUser = await GoogleSignIn(scopes: ['profile', 'email']).signIn();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it solved my problem

Comment: I had the same issue on S23 Ultra. The function works fine on other Android devices. This solution fixed the issue for me as well. Thanks. But do you happen to know why is that?

Answer (score 0):

May be your emulator doesn't support Google Play
And you should Add firebase-auth and google-sign-in dependencies